# How can I increase a number found by wildcard in the previous command? (zsh)

Tags: shell, zsh, wildcards, command-history, history-expansion

I want to accomplish this:

```
setopt HIST_SUBST_PATTERN
echo Ninja_Turtles_2003_S02E05_DVDRip_30NAMA.mkv
^E(0?)^E$((match[1]+1))
# resulting in:
echo Ninja_Turtles_2003_S02E06_DVDRip_30NAMA.mkv
```

‌But I get:

```
echo Ninja_Turtles_2003_S02E1_DVDRip_30NAMA.mkv
```

I tried `^(#b)E(0?)^E$((match[1]+1))`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `extendedglob` option for `(#b)`.

Also `05 + 1` yields `6`, not `06`.

You could do (with `extendedglob` and `histsubstpattern`)

```
^(#b)E(<->)^E${(l:2::0:)$((match[1]+1))}
```

Or:

```
echo ${_//(#b)E(<->)/${(l:2::0:)$((match[1]+1))}
```

- `<->` is a form of `<x-y>` positive decimal number matching operator where both boundaries are omitted, so matches any non-empty sequence of decimal digits. Same as `[0-9]##` (though `##` needs extended-glob while `<x-y>` doesn't).
- `(l:2::0:)` (note that it's a lower case L, not the `1` digit) is the left-padding parameter expansion flag, here with `0`s, of length `2`.

Comment: What are the `<->` and `(1:2::0:)`?

Comment: @HappyFace, see edit.

Comment: Can you help with this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466540/how-can-i-alias-a-history-expansion-in-zsh