# Alternative of bash's `history -p` in zsh?

Tags: zsh, command-history, history-expansion, fc

In bash, `history -p` does history expansion on its argument; What is the alternative in zsh?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any, but see the `histverify` option which changes the behaviour of history expansion so that when you press enter on a line that contains history operators, the expansion is performed in the editor buffer without running the command.

```
$ setopt histverify
$ echo !!Enter
$ echo setopt histverifyEnter
setopt histverify
```

Also note that in `zsh` like in `csh` (where history expansion comes from in the late 70s) history modifiers (like `:h`, `:r`, `:A`...) can also be applied to parameter expansions (`$var:h`...).

And the whole history is accessible with the `$history` special associative array.

Keys of that associative arrays are the history numbers, and contrary to regular  associative arrays where the order is undefined, `$history[@]` is sorted in descending order on the numerical value of the key.

So `${history:0:1}` is the last history entry. So, you can use parameter expansion operators to get the same result as with history expansion operators. For instance: `!$:h`, could be `${${(z)history:0:1}[-1]:h}`

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can expand a command by doing this:

```
history -p !23
```

So if in 23 you have ls -l the, return will be:

```
ls 
-l
```

In zsh i am able to reproduce a similar (but not identical) behavior by doing this:

```
history 23 23 | xargs -n1 | tail -n+2
```

Comment: ITYM `history -p '!23'`. In `zsh`, just use `print -r -- $history[23]`

Comment: I tried but nothing happens =(. Try history -p !23 instead of history -p '!23'... for what is really that ? =(

Comment: Thanks, but I need more sophisticated behavior; I wanted to run `history -p '^(#b)E(?)^E${(l:2::0:)$((match[1]+1))}'`. I wrote that function using `fc` in the end.

Comment: I cant imagine the results you want to got. I just received "History Expansion Failed" (in bash). Can you post in you question what you have, and what exactly you want to get or do? Thank you. Maybe i have a easy solution!